# difference between \verb and \NewDocumentCommand verb

Tags: verbatim, xparse

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}    
\NewDocumentCommand{\myVerbatim}{v}{#1}

\myVerbatim|This is some text, which can contain $\sin(x)$ or code or $$|

\verb|This is some text, which can contain $\sin(x)$ or code $$|
\end{document}
```

Produces, using lualatex, this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I thought they should come out the same. Why are they different?

From manual

[image: Mathematica graphics]

TL 2015

Comment: `\verb` is a typesetting command: a `v`-type argument is about 'grabbing' stuff, what you do with it is down to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual doesn't say that a font selection is done when delivering the argument after it has grabbed “in a way similar to `\verb`” just because it *doesn't* happen in the first place. So

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myVerbatim}{v}{\texttt{#1}}
```

will emulate `\verb` (but `\verb` does some more things).